# NextAuth.js - Adding extra properties to Session

Tags: typescript, authentication, discord, next-auth

I am trying to authenticate users with Discord using the "identify" and "guilds" scopes. It seems to be possible to add the user info provided by Discord into the token into `token.profile` (note I am also including the guilds array there as well) using this code:

```
async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) {
    if (profile) token.profile = profile;
    if (account?.accessToken) token.accessToken = account.accessToken;

    const data = await (
        await fetch("https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/guilds", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${account?.accessToken}`,
            },
        })
    ).json();

    // @ts-ignore
    token.profile.guilds = data;

    return token;
},
```

But, as soon as I add a `session` function that adds the `profile` object into the session, the session becomes `null` all the time even when signed in, and the login screen from Discord prompts me to enter username and password instead of just automatically letting me in.

```
// @ts-ignore
async session(session, token) {
    console.log("token", token);
    console.log("session", session);

    // @ts-ignore
    session.profile = token.profile;

    return session;
},
```

*As a side-note, the reason I have to add so many `@ts-ignore`s in the `session` function is that it expects a `Promise<WithAdditionalParams<Session>>` while I only return a `Promise<Session>`, not sure how to fix that.*

Can anyone help me add the information I receive from Discord into the `session` so that I can use it in my application?